How to find the unique real number in $a \in [1.4,1.5]$ such that the function $a^{x}-x$ has unique root?
How to find the unique real number in $a \in [1.4,1.5]$  such that the function $a^{x}-x$ has unique root?
My motivation to this question is just that I was exploring graphs of $b^{x}-x$ on Desoms for different values of $b$ , and I noticed that for $b \in [1,a]$ where $a$ is the unique number I am seeking, we have two roots, while for $b \in (a,\infty)$, we have no roots.
Please see the link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zebm1ouhnx
I tried to estimate the solution for $a$ by desmos, it's approximately $1.44466786$, but I am not sure because this constant $a$ may be irrational, but desmos just is approximating it.
And I think that the unique root to $a^x-x$ is $x=e$.

$a^{x}-x$ is not an equation.

@geetha290krm Sorry I will correct it

By the guidance of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3813068/870236
Let's write $a^x=x$, then $a=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$.
Let $y=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$.
$$\ln{y}=\frac{1}{x}\ln{x}$$
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{x^{2}}(1-\ln{x})$$
$$y'=(1-\ln{x})x^{\frac{1}{x}-2}$$
$y'=0$ if $x=e$, and we have maximum at $e$ since the derivative of $y$ is positive for the values less than $e$ and negative for the values greater than $e$.
So, the only output of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ that has only one input is $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ .
And of course $a=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ is irrational is conjecture, because the conjectures are more than what is known when it comes to irrational numbers!
